# "The order of a differential equation is the highest derivative in the equation". What's wrong with this statement?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

I am asked the following

> "The order of a differential equation is the highest derivative in the equation". What's wrong with this statement?

I've checked my text and several other sources, and the statement above is what they have used to define the order of a differential equation. So what am I missing here that makes this statement false or insufficient?

One counter example I do see to the definition is $$y'''+y''x=y'''+2y$$
Since 
$$y'''+y''x=y'''+2y \Leftrightarrow xy''-2y=0$$

Comment: Nothing is realy wrong with the statement. If one is intent on playing it smart, one can note that the simplification argument in your post can also fail. Consider for example $y'+|x|=y'+y$. This differential equation has no solution on $(-1,1)$, say, while the differential equation (of zeroth order) that one obtains after the manipulations in your post is $y=|x|$, which is not equivalent to $y'+|x|=y'+y$ since it has one solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the given ODE can be written in the form
$$y^{(n)}(t)=F\bigl(t,y(t),y'(t),\ldots,y^{(n-1)}(t)\bigr)$$ then it is of *order* $n$. If the  ODE is given in the form
$$G\bigl(t,y(t),y'(t),\ldots,y^{(n)}(t)\bigr)\equiv0$$
then it is an *implicit* ODE of order $n$, and the standard theorems about ODE's cannot be applied without caution.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider only linear operators (aka linear differential equations) then the order is the dimension of the null-space or kernel of the linear operator that produces the differential equation. This takes care of your counter examples with third derivatives.

Example: $y''-y'-y=y''\iff(-\frac{d}{dx}-1)y=0$ so the linear operator we are interested in is $(-\frac{d}{dx}-1)$ which has kernel of dimension 1. Thus even though the differential equation has 2nd order derivatives, it turns out to be a 1st order problem.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting perspective; I haven't read anything of this flavor in my textbook. Is this something that comes up in an introductory differential equations course.?